# Assembly hacking game, need the password

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-64

The file "decoded" is written and converted to assembly.
The program takes in a number; say 50, and compare it with a predefined constant: Example

```
>>decoded 50 //if the number is equal to the predefined constant number then you pass.
```

The file runs as a program called decoded so I had to use this command

```
>>objdump -d decoded
```

to see the assembly code. (Below is the code).

I have been looking at this assembly code for a while trying to figure out the output and the movements between memory and registry and the assigned values to find out the predefined constant in the program in order to pass.
I have payed attention to all the values after the $ sign and saw where they are stored. I also payed attention to the add cmpl and mov.
I got these values:

> rsi is 8 + 1 
>   edi is 4196104 + 1 + 4196192 + 4196240 
>   eax is 101010101010 + 0
>   I am assuming all under (Rbp) in memory.

I ran the program with those value and tried variety of combination and it did not let me pass. I feel like I am not fully understanding the assembly codes and how they work.

```
000000000040060d <main>:
  40060d:       55                      push   %rbp
  40060e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400611:       48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  400615:       89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  400618:       48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  40061c:       c7 45 fc 12 eb 34 3c    movl   $0x3c34eb12,-0x4(%rbp)
  400623:       83 7d ec 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x14(%rbp)
  400627:       7f 19                   jg     400642 <main+0x35>
  400629:       bf 08 07 40 00          mov    $0x400708,%edi
  40062e:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400633:       e8 98 fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <printf@plt>
  400638:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40063d:       e8 ce fe ff ff          callq  400510 <exit@plt>
  400642:       48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  400646:       48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
  40064a:       48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  40064d:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400650:       e8 ab fe ff ff          callq  400500 <atoi@plt>
  400655:       3b 45 fc                cmp    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400658:       74 0c                   je     400666 <main+0x59>
  40065a:       bf 60 07 40 00          mov    $0x400760,%edi
  40065f:       e8 5c fe ff ff          callq  4004c0 <puts@plt>
  400664:       eb 0a                   jmp    400670 <main+0x63>
  400666:       bf 90 07 40 00          mov    $0x400790,%edi
  40066b:       e8 50 fe ff ff          callq  4004c0 <puts@plt>
  400670:       c9                      leaveq
  400671:       c3                      retq
  400672:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400679:       00 00 00
  40067c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

The full program is below, I only payed attention to the main function though.

```
Disassembly of section .init:

0000000000400488 <_init>:
  400488:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  40048c:       48 8b 05 65 0b 20 00    mov    0x200b65(%rip),%rax        # 600ff8 <_DYNAMIC+0x1d0>
  400493:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  400496:       74 05                   je     40049d <_init+0x15>
  400498:       e8 53 00 00 00          callq  4004f0 <__gmon_start__@plt>
  40049d:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4004a1:       c3                      retq

Disassembly of section .plt:

00000000004004b0 <puts@plt-0x10>:
  4004b0:       ff 35 52 0b 20 00       pushq  0x200b52(%rip)        # 601008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
  4004b6:       ff 25 54 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200b54(%rip)        # 601010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
  4004bc:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

00000000004004c0 <puts@plt>:
  4004c0:       ff 25 52 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200b52(%rip)        # 601018 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x18>
  4004c6:       68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
  4004cb:       e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   4004b0 <_init+0x28>

00000000004004d0 <printf@plt>:
  4004d0:       ff 25 4a 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200b4a(%rip)        # 601020 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x20>
  4004d6:       68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
  4004db:       e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   4004b0 <_init+0x28>

00000000004004e0 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
  4004e0:       ff 25 42 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200b42(%rip)        # 601028 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x28>
  4004e6:       68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
  4004eb:       e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmpq   4004b0 <_init+0x28>

00000000004004f0 <__gmon_start__@plt>:
  4004f0:       ff 25 3a 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200b3a(%rip)        # 601030 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x30>
  4004f6:       68 03 00 00 00          pushq  $0x3
  4004fb:       e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmpq   4004b0 <_init+0x28>

0000000000400500 <atoi@plt>:
  400500:       ff 25 32 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200b32(%rip)        # 601038 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x38>
  400506:       68 04 00 00 00          pushq  $0x4
  40050b:       e9 a0 ff ff ff          jmpq   4004b0 <_init+0x28>

0000000000400510 <exit@plt>:
  400510:       ff 25 2a 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200b2a(%rip)        # 601040 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x40>
  400516:       68 05 00 00 00          pushq  $0x5
  40051b:       e9 90 ff ff ff          jmpq   4004b0 <_init+0x28>

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400520 <_start>:
  400520:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400522:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  400525:       5e                      pop    %rsi
  400526:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  400529:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  40052d:       50                      push   %rax
  40052e:       54                      push   %rsp
  40052f:       49 c7 c0 f0 06 40 00    mov    $0x4006f0,%r8
  400536:       48 c7 c1 80 06 40 00    mov    $0x400680,%rcx
  40053d:       48 c7 c7 0d 06 40 00    mov    $0x40060d,%rdi
  400544:       e8 97 ff ff ff          callq  4004e0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
  400549:       f4                      hlt
  40054a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000400550 <deregister_tm_clones>:
  400550:       b8 5f 10 60 00          mov    $0x60105f,%eax
  400555:       55                      push   %rbp
  400556:       48 2d 58 10 60 00       sub    $0x601058,%rax
  40055c:       48 83 f8 0e             cmp    $0xe,%rax
  400560:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400563:       77 02                   ja     400567 <deregister_tm_clones+0x17>
  400565:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400566:       c3                      retq
  400567:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40056c:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  40056f:       74 f4                   je     400565 <deregister_tm_clones+0x15>
  400571:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400572:       bf 58 10 60 00          mov    $0x601058,%edi
  400577:       ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
  400579:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400580 <register_tm_clones>:
  400580:       b8 58 10 60 00          mov    $0x601058,%eax
  400585:       55                      push   %rbp
  400586:       48 2d 58 10 60 00       sub    $0x601058,%rax
  40058c:       48 c1 f8 03             sar    $0x3,%rax
  400590:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400593:       48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  400596:       48 c1 ea 3f             shr    $0x3f,%rdx
  40059a:       48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
  40059d:       48 d1 f8                sar    %rax
  4005a0:       75 02                   jne    4005a4 <register_tm_clones+0x24>
  4005a2:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005a3:       c3                      retq
  4005a4:       ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  4005a9:       48 85 d2                test   %rdx,%rdx
  4005ac:       74 f4                   je     4005a2 <register_tm_clones+0x22>
  4005ae:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005af:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  4005b2:       bf 58 10 60 00          mov    $0x601058,%edi
  4005b7:       ff e2                   jmpq   *%rdx
  4005b9:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

00000000004005c0 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
  4005c0:       80 3d 91 0a 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x200a91(%rip)        # 601058 <__TMC_END__>
  4005c7:       75 11                   jne    4005da <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x1a>
  4005c9:       55                      push   %rbp
  4005ca:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005cd:       e8 7e ff ff ff          callq  400550 <deregister_tm_clones>
  4005d2:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005d3:       c6 05 7e 0a 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x200a7e(%rip)        # 601058 <__TMC_END__>
  4005da:       f3 c3                   repz retq
  4005dc:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

00000000004005e0 <frame_dummy>:
  4005e0:       48 83 3d 38 08 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x200838(%rip)        # 600e20 <__JCR_END__>
  4005e7:       00
  4005e8:       74 1e                   je     400608 <frame_dummy+0x28>
  4005ea:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4005ef:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4005f2:       74 14                   je     400608 <frame_dummy+0x28>
  4005f4:       55                      push   %rbp
  4005f5:       bf 20 0e 60 00          mov    $0x600e20,%edi
  4005fa:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005fd:       ff d0                   callq  *%rax
  4005ff:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  400600:       e9 7b ff ff ff          jmpq   400580 <register_tm_clones>
  400605:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  400608:       e9 73 ff ff ff          jmpq   400580 <register_tm_clones>

000000000040060d <main>:
  40060d:       55                      push   %rbp
  40060e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400611:       48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  400615:       89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  400618:       48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  40061c:       c7 45 fc 12 eb 34 3c    movl   $0x3c34eb12,-0x4(%rbp)
  400623:       83 7d ec 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x14(%rbp)
  400627:       7f 19                   jg     400642 <main+0x35>
  400629:       bf 08 07 40 00          mov    $0x400708,%edi
  40062e:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400633:       e8 98 fe ff ff          callq  4004d0 <printf@plt>
  400638:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40063d:       e8 ce fe ff ff          callq  400510 <exit@plt>
  400642:       48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  400646:       48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
  40064a:       48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  40064d:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400650:       e8 ab fe ff ff          callq  400500 <atoi@plt>
  400655:       3b 45 fc                cmp    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  400658:       74 0c                   je     400666 <main+0x59>
  40065a:       bf 60 07 40 00          mov    $0x400760,%edi
  40065f:       e8 5c fe ff ff          callq  4004c0 <puts@plt>
  400664:       eb 0a                   jmp    400670 <main+0x63>
  400666:       bf 90 07 40 00          mov    $0x400790,%edi
  40066b:       e8 50 fe ff ff          callq  4004c0 <puts@plt>
  400670:       c9                      leaveq
  400671:       c3                      retq
  400672:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400679:       00 00 00
  40067c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400680 <__libc_csu_init>:
  400680:       41 57                   push   %r15
  400682:       41 89 ff                mov    %edi,%r15d
  400685:       41 56                   push   %r14
  400687:       49 89 f6                mov    %rsi,%r14
  40068a:       41 55                   push   %r13
  40068c:       49 89 d5                mov    %rdx,%r13
  40068f:       41 54                   push   %r12
  400691:       4c 8d 25 78 07 20 00    lea    0x200778(%rip),%r12        # 600e10 <__frame_dummy_init_array_entry>
  400698:       55                      push   %rbp
  400699:       48 8d 2d 78 07 20 00    lea    0x200778(%rip),%rbp        # 600e18 <__init_array_end>
  4006a0:       53                      push   %rbx
  4006a1:       4c 29 e5                sub    %r12,%rbp
  4006a4:       31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  4006a6:       48 c1 fd 03             sar    $0x3,%rbp
  4006aa:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4006ae:       e8 d5 fd ff ff          callq  400488 <_init>
  4006b3:       48 85 ed                test   %rbp,%rbp
  4006b6:       74 1e                   je     4006d6 <__libc_csu_init+0x56>
  4006b8:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4006bf:       00
  4006c0:       4c 89 ea                mov    %r13,%rdx
  4006c3:       4c 89 f6                mov    %r14,%rsi
  4006c6:       44 89 ff                mov    %r15d,%edi
  4006c9:       41 ff 14 dc             callq  *(%r12,%rbx,8)
  4006cd:       48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
  4006d1:       48 39 eb                cmp    %rbp,%rbx
  4006d4:       75 ea                   jne    4006c0 <__libc_csu_init+0x40>
  4006d6:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4006da:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  4006db:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4006dc:       41 5c                   pop    %r12
  4006de:       41 5d                   pop    %r13
  4006e0:       41 5e                   pop    %r14
  4006e2:       41 5f                   pop    %r15
  4006e4:       c3                      retq
  4006e5:       66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4006ec:       00 00 00 00

00000000004006f0 <__libc_csu_fini>:
  4006f0:       f3 c3                   repz retq

Disassembly of section .fini:

00000000004006f4 <_fini>:
  4006f4:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4006f8:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4006fc:       c3                      retq
```

Comment: Walk it through a debugger.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I will try to see if can take the file from linux and debug in another software where it tells me what is going on operation by operation

Comment: Just from a quick glance it should be obvious that it calls `atoi` and the result is then compared to `-4(%rbp)` which is set from a constant earlier. That is your password. You need to convert from hex of course.

Comment: Thank you, so all the other commands are not necessary to find the password?